# ¿Como obtener promedio y el mayor de una lista de números?

Tags: algoritmos, pseudocódigo

Dado el arreglo números A: 20,8,2,15,10,4,50 hacer un algoritmo que determine cual es el numero mayor y calcular el promedio del arreglo (no lo ocupo para Pseint,es en el cuaderno) es un Pseudocódigo. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
A = array   [7]Integer= 20,8,2,15,10,4,50
promedio i, mayor : integer;

Begin

for ( i=0; i <=6; i=i+1)
```

Comment: Hola Isis, deberías poner el código que haz intentado hasta el momento, ya que una pregunta como la tuya es candidata a ser cerrada.

Comment: Hola, ¿Podrías añadir más información a la Pregunta? _"Qué has intentado"_, como, código de ejemplo. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta siguiendo las [directrices de calidad](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Como verás [es.SO] no es un sustituto de Google; la investigación y los intentos van por tu cuenta.

Comment: No esperes que te hagan la tarea aquí.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Un programa en Java para hacer esto es

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 20, 8, 2, 15, 10, 4, 50 };
        float promedio = 0;
        int mayor = 0, 
            largo = a.length;  // esta es la cantidad de elementos en el vector

        for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++){

            // si el mayor es menor que el indice "i"
            if (a[mayor] < a[i]){
                // entonces asignar "i" a "mayor"
                mayor = i;
            }

            // sumar en "promedio" todos los elementos del vector
            promedio = promedio + a[i];
        }

        // dividir la suma de "promedio" por la cantidad de elementos del vector
        promedio = promedio / a.length;

        // imprimir los resultados por la salida estandar
        System.out.println("prom=" + promedio + " mayor=" + a[mayor] );
    }
}
```

Comment: si he intentando la cuestion es que estoy empezando y el tema de arreglo se me hace complicado .

Comment: @IsisMejia ya tienes un algoritmo. mira un sitio como [este](http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/~jmmartinez/Pseudocodigo.htm) para trasformarlo a pseudocódigo.

Comment: gracias Arie CwHat